# How can I start chrome in insecure mode in mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, websecurity

I know how to Start chrome in insecure mode via command line with these options: --disable-web-security --disable-gpu. How can I do it in MAC OS?
So i am going inside the location where chrome is installed and running this command

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

But it is throwing error `zsh: command not found: chrome.exe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, this is the correct command (Mac does not open .exe files):

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome
```

You need to specify both arguments for the command to work. The first one to disable web security and the second one to specify a folder where Chrome will create the temporary profile and keep the necessary data.

Comment: I used the exact command, how can i know if it worked or not?

Comment: Ensure that no Chrome window is open. Open terminal and execute the command in the answer above. If the command works you will see a new chrome blank window with a new profile (you won't see your bookmarks, history, etc...)

Comment: okay and how do we get back to normal mode?

Comment: Just close chrome completely and open it using the regular icon

Comment: @AlfonsMuñoz how can I create shortcut or something like that to avoid run every time this command in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to open a new Chrome window with a url already specified:

```
open -n -a Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir http://localhost:3000/ --disable-web-security
```